# How do I create a common column key or string for currency bought and sold dynamically to cater for all opposite currencies. E.g. USD/GBP and GBP/USD

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I create a common column whereby I can later on group bought and sold currency in a pair.

If USD is traded to GBP, then GBP is traded for USD. They are a pair regardless of the date
If EURO is traded to USD, then USD is traded for EURO. Then this is another pair.
And so forth with all the other currencies, but other currencies are always paired with USD

Sample data below

```sql
CREATE TABLE FX_Buy_Sell
(
    --Common_key VARCHAR(12) NULL, 
    Tradedate DATE NULL, 
    Symbol_from VARCHAR(4) NULL, 
    SourceAmount DECIMAL(18,2) NULL,
    Symbol_to VARCHAR(4) NULL,
    TradeAmount DECIMAL(18,2) NULL,
);


INSERT INTO FX_Buy_Sell (Tradedate,Symbol_from,SourceAmount,Symbol_to,TradeAmount)
VALUES
('2019-01-29','USD',39394.8,'GBP',31000),
('2019-01-29','USD',27914.34,'GBP',21700),
('2019-01-29','USD',77342.97,'GBP',59300),
('2019-03-29','USD',81908.2,'GBP',620000),
('2019-05-23','USD',101776,'GBP',80000),
('2019-07-25','USD',105706,'GBP',85000),
('2019-09-06','USD',127459.49,'GBP',106000),
('2019-11-08','USD',158937.77,'GBP',123000),
('2019-12-09','USD',90213.62,'GBP',70000),
('2019-12-09','USD',76256.43,'GBP',58000),
('2019-01-29','GBP',112000,'USD',143262),
('2019-03-29','GBP',62000,'USD',81102.2),
('2019-05-23','GBP',80000,'USD',105976),
('2019-07-25','GBP',85000,'USD',108483.38),
('2019-09-06','GBP',106000,'USD',132079.18),
('2019-11-08','GBP',123000,'USD',148276.5),
('2019-12-09','GBP',128000,'USD',165548.8),
('2019-01-29','EURO',17000,'USD',19322.2),
('2019-09-06','EURO',19000,'USD',21289.5),
('2019-11-08','EURO',10000,'USD',10996),
('2019-01-29','USD',19532.83,'EURO',17000),
('2019-09-06','USD',20793.24,'EURO',19000),
('2019-11-08','USD',11163.42,'EURO',10000);
```

I tried to self join and concatenate the symbols, also tried to create a key. but it is not giving me the desired results:

select * from
(
SELECT
Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY fb.Symbol_from, fbs.Symbol_to   ORDER BY fbs.Symbol_to,fb.Symbol_to, fbs.Symbol_from ) as COMMON_STRING_KEY,
IIF(fb.Symbol_from = fbs.Symbol_to, fbs.Symbol_to + fb.Symbol_from +fb.Symbol_to + fbs.Symbol_from, 'Null') as COMMON_STRING_KEY2,
fb.*
FROM FX_Buy_Sell fb
left outer  JOIN FX_Buy_Sell fbs
ON fb.Symbol_from = fbs.Symbol_to
) a
where a.COMMON_STRING_KEY = 1

Expected results, I need a column with some sort of common key or string that I can use to group the currency pairs(bought and sold) with:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         table, th, td {
         border: 1px solid black;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Desired outcome</h1>
      <table>
         <thead>
         

            <tr>
               <th>Common_String_Key</th>
               <th>Tradedate</th>
               <th>Symbol_From</th>
               <th>SourceAmount</th>
               <th>DestSymbol_To</th>
               <th>TradeAmount</th>
            </tr>
            

         </thead>
         <tbody>
         

            <tr>
               <td>USDGBP_BGPUSD</td>
               <td>2019-01-29</td>
               <td>USD</td>
               <td>-39394.8</td>
               <td>GBP</td>
               <td>31000</td>
            </tr>
            

            <tr>
               <td>USDGBP_BGPUSD</td>
               <td>2019-01-29</td>
               <td>USD</td>
               <td>-27914.34</td>
               <td>GBP</td>
               <td>21700</td>
            </tr>
            

            <tr>
               <td>USDGBP_BGPUSD</td>
               <td>2019-01-29</td>
               <td>USD</td>
               <td>-77342.97</td>
               <td>GBP</td>
               <td>59300</td>
            </tr>
            

            <tr>
               <td>USDGBP_BGPUSD</td>
               <td>2019-03-29</td>
               <td>USD</td>
               <td>-81908.2</td>
               <td>GBP</td>
               <td>62000</td>
            </tr>
            

            <tr>
               <td>USDGBP_BGPUSD</td>
               <td>2019-05-23</td>
               <td>USD</td>
               <td>-101776</td>
               <td>GBP</td>
               <td>80000</td>
            </tr>
            

            <tr>
               <td>USDGBP_BGPUSD</td>
               <td>2019-07-25</td>
               <td>USD</td>
               <td>-105706</td>
               <td>GBP</td>
               <td>85000</td>
            </tr>
            

            <tr>
               <td>USDGBP_BGPUSD</td>
               <td>2019-09-06</td>
               <td>USD</td>
               <td>-127459.49</td>
               <td>GBP</td>
               <td>106000</td>
            </tr>
            

            <tr>
               <td>USDGBP_BGPUSD</td>
               <td>2019-11-08</td>
               <td>USD</td>
               <td>-158937.77</td>
               <td>GBP</td>
               <td>123000</td>
            </tr>
            

            <tr>
               <td>USDGBP_BGPUSD</td>
               <td>2019-12-09</td>
               <td>USD</td>
               <td>-90213.62</td>
               <td>GBP</td>
               <td>70000</td>
            </tr>
            

            <tr>
               <td>USDGBP_BGPUSD</td>
               <td>2019-12-09</td>
               <td>USD</td>
               <td>-76256.43</td>
               <td>GBP</td>
               <td>58000</td>
            </tr>
            

            <tr>
               <td>USDGBP_BGPUSD</td>
               <td>2019-01-29</td>
               <td>GBP</td>
               <td>-112000</td>
               <td>USD</td>
               <td>143262</td>
            </tr>
            

            <tr>
               <td>USDGBP_BGPUSD</td>
               <td>2019-03-29</td>
               <td>GBP</td>
               <td>-62000</td>
               <td>USD</td>
               <td>81102.2</td>
            </tr>
            

            <tr>
               <td>USDGBP_BGPUSD</td>
               <td>2019-05-23</td>
               <td>GBP</td>
               <td>-80000</td>
               <td>USD</td>
               <td>105976</td>
            </tr>
            

            <tr>
               <td>USDGBP_BGPUSD</td>
               <td>2019-07-25</td>
               <td>GBP</td>
               <td>-85000</td>
               <td>USD</td>
               <td>108483.38</td>
            </tr>
            

            <tr>
               <td>USDGBP_BGPUSD</td>
               <td>2019-09-06</td>
               <td>GBP</td>
               <td>-106000</td>
               <td>USD</td>
               <td>132079.18</td>
            </tr>
            

            <tr>
               <td>USDGBP_BGPUSD</td>
               <td>2019-11-08</td>
               <td>GBP</td>
               <td>-123000</td>
               <td>USD</td>
               <td>148276.5</td>
            </tr>
            

            <tr>
               <td>USDGBP_BGPUSD</td>
               <td>2019-12-09</td>
               <td>GBP</td>
               <td>-39394.8</td>
               <td>USD</td>
               <td>165548.8</td>
            </tr>
            

            <tr>
               <td>USDEURO_EURO_USD</td>
               <td>2019-01-29</td>
               <td>EURO</td>
               <td>-17000</td>
               <td>USD</td>
               <td>19322.2</td>
            </tr>
            

            <tr>
               <td>USDEURO_EURO_USD</td>
               <td>2019-09-06</td>
               <td>EURO</td>
               <td>-19000</td>
               <td>USD</td>
               <td>21289.5</td>
            </tr>
            

            <tr>
               <td>USDEURO_EURO_USD</td>
               <td>2019-11-08</td>
               <td>EURO</td>
               <td>-10000</td>
               <td>USD</td>
               <td>10996</td>
            </tr>
            

            <tr>
               <td>USDEURO_EURO_USD</td>
               <td>2019-01-29</td>
               <td>USD</td>
               <td>-19532.83</td>
               <td>EURO</td>
               <td>17000</td>
            </tr>
            

            <tr>
               <td>USDEURO_EURO_USD</td>
               <td>2019-09-06</td>
               <td>USD</td>
               <td>-20793.24</td>
               <td>EURO</td>
               <td>19000</td>
            </tr>
            

            <tr>
               <td>USDEURO_EURO_USD</td>
               <td>2019-11-08</td>
               <td>USD</td>
               <td>-11163.42</td>
               <td>EURO</td>
               <td>10000</td>
            </tr>
            

         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is *your* question here. [so] isn't a free coding service. You say you "need" but you don't tell us what the problem is. If you need something, what's stopping you from getting it?

Comment: Unfortunately the expected results is showing first on the post. I would like to create a common column whereby I can later on group bought and sold currency in a pair. All the information is below the table with expected results. Is this the correct place to ask for help?

Comment: Not really. [so] isn't a help forum, it's a Q&A site (if you read the [tour] like you were prompted to when you signed up you'd know this). If you have a question, the users here are happy to try to answer it, but you haven't asked a question, so we can't provide an answer.

Comment: Is there ever any data that _doesn't_ have USD in it? Going by your sample data it seems like you just need to group on whatever currency is _not_ USD and that's enough to group records together

Comment: `USDGBP_BGPUSD` BGP - really? And why does `USDEURO_EURO_USD` get an bonus underscore? Why the duplication and reversal within the string? And the ISO code for the euro is EUR. Bad and inconsistent habit die hard. It seems this is just simple concatenation with minimal rules at best - or just use the "other" currency as Nick suggests. Seems like your approach is just overly complicated.

Comment: Please don't replace mark down tables with HTML. The markdown table was far more consumable and readable. Also, as you can see in the original edit I did, code fences are supported; make use of them. Take the time to improve the formatting in your question that you undid from my previous [edit].

Comment: After several attempts at Google-fu, @SMor, "BGP" might be a crypto currency called "Big Capital Price". I'm sceptical of the results I found though, if I am honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution
NOTE: to get this to work I had to add a unique id to each row

CREATE TABLE #FX_Buy_Sell2
(
id int identity(1,1),
Tradedate DATE NULL,
Symbol_from VARCHAR(4) NULL,
SourceAmount DECIMAL(18,2) NULL,
Symbol_to VARCHAR(4) NULL,
TradeAmount DECIMAL(18,2) NULL,
Common_key VARCHAR(12) NULL
);

INSERT INTO #FX_Buy_Sell2 (Tradedate,Symbol_from,SourceAmount,Symbol_to,TradeAmount)
VALUES
('2019-01-29','USD',39394.8,'GBP',31000),
('2019-01-29','USD',27914.34,'GBP',21700),
('2019-01-29','USD',77342.97,'GBP',59300),
('2019-03-29','USD',81908.2,'GBP',620000),
('2019-05-23','USD',101776,'GBP',80000),
('2019-07-25','USD',105706,'GBP',85000),
('2019-09-06','USD',127459.49,'GBP',106000),
('2019-11-08','USD',158937.77,'GBP',123000),
('2019-12-09','USD',90213.62,'GBP',70000),
('2019-12-09','USD',76256.43,'GBP',58000),
('2019-01-29','GBP',112000,'USD',143262),
('2019-03-29','GBP',62000,'USD',81102.2),
('2019-05-23','GBP',80000,'USD',105976),
('2019-07-25','GBP',85000,'USD',108483.38),
('2019-09-06','GBP',106000,'USD',132079.18),
('2019-11-08','GBP',123000,'USD',148276.5),
('2019-12-09','GBP',128000,'USD',165548.8),
('2019-01-29','EURO',17000,'USD',19322.2),
('2019-09-06','EURO',19000,'USD',21289.5),
('2019-11-08','EURO',10000,'USD',10996),
('2019-01-29','USD',19532.83,'EURO',17000),
('2019-09-06','USD',20793.24,'EURO',19000),
('2019-11-08','USD',11163.42,'EURO',10000);

using UNPIVOT (Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs[^]) and FOR XML (FOR XML (SQL Server) - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs[^])

Approach - get a list of symbol_from and symbol_to for each row in alphabetic order, then combine those values into a single value

with cte1 as
(
SELECT id, code
FROM
(SELECT id, symbol_from, symbol_to
FROM #FX_Buy_Sell2) p
UNPIVOT
(code FOR symbol IN
(symbol_from, symbol_to)
)AS unpvt
),cte2 as
(
select id, stuff((SELECT ' ' + code from cte1 b where a.id = b.id ORDER BY code
for XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as combo from cte1 a
GROUP BY id
)
update a set Common_key = b.combo
from #FX_Buy_Sell2 a
inner join cte2 b on a.id = b.id;

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for answering but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the issue? Also check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how to format code.